# Low resolution on the logon screen in Xubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: graphics, xubuntu, display-resolution, amd-graphics

I installed Xubuntu 20.04LTS on my Fujitsu-Siemens Amilo Pi2540 laptop with Mobility Radeon HD2400 graphics. I set the system resolution to native 1200x800 and that's fine, but the login screen is still at a low resolution and it bothers me. I tried changing grub resolution but that didn't help. Any sugestions? I had the same issue on Mint, but i remember it worked just fine on Debian 10. Has anyone had this issue and know how to fix it Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i managed to fix it already. Hope that if you have this issue i helped solve it!

- Install arandr
- Run it and set the laptop's display as main, to native resolution
- Save the file to the desktop as `monitor-config.sh`
- Open terminal
- `sudo -i`
- Copy this file to `/etc/lightdm`
- Create empty file on desktop and name it `lightdm.conf`
- Open with a text editor and put this in it:

  ```
  [Seat:*]
  display-setup-script=/etc/lightdm/monitor-config.sh
  ```
- Again copy this file to `/etc/lightdm`
- Reboot

All done, working perfectly.